# How can I change the default color of the button on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

How can I change the default color of the button on iPhone?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A common technique is to use an image for the background. Actually you can use a stretchable image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *blueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
    UIImage *blueButtonImage = [blueImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:blueButtonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

The original image:

[image]

The end result:

[image]

Comment: how can one make your own colored buttons? Say yellow instead of blue png? does anyone have a photoshop tutorial link for such a thing?

Comment: You can use the iPhone Style Icon Tutorial to get you started:
http://www.keepthewebweird.com/iphone-style-icon-tutorial/

Comment: do you have the green and red version of this image too?

Answer (score 6):

I came across this post that explains how to do this without images and completely in code.

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean `UIButton`, you can only change the title color using `setTitleColor:forState:`.

You can't change the background color or the shape. You have to create your own control for that.

Answer (score 0):

I started [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22448-other-colors-bluebutton-png-uicatalog-sample-code.html) on iphonedevsdk.com.

Hopefully we'll get an answer there if not here.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to customize UIButtons is by directly manipulating the Core Animation Layers. You can find a good tutorial on "Cocoa is My Girlfriend"

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/