# how can i set the background color of a particular button in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

How can I set the background color of a particular button in iPhone?

I used:

```
btnName1 = [ColorfulButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnName1.frame=CGRectMake(45,146,220,40);
[btnName1 setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[btnName1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[btnName1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *img =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"greenish" ofType:@"png"]];
UIImage *strechableImage = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[btnName1 setBackgroundImage:strechableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnName1 setNeedsDisplay];
[InfoView addSubview:btnName1];
```

It's correctly working on iPhone simulator but not on iPod (color not shown in iPod).

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948106/how-can-i-change-the-default-color-of-the-button-on-iphone

Answer (score 5):

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Or whatever colour you want. This method is inherited from `UIView`.

Note that this only sets the background colour...

If you want to change the button's look:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can change the state to whichever state you like.

EDIT: If you are adding the button from interface builder, make sure to change the button `Type` to `Custom`, and change the `image`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it done.

1. In the .h file declare yourButton as an IBOutlet.

   ```
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
   ```
2. In the .m file where you want to change the colour of the button use either

   ```
   [yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
   ```

or

```
[yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.80 green:0.80 blue:0.80 alpha:1.0]];
```

To obtain the colours I require I use [this](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/ios-uicolor-picker) link.

Answer (score 0):

i had the solution when code is written in viewdidload() it's properly work eariler i used for uiview thatswhy it's not work.